# Wordpress "uploads/wp-less-cache/theme-less.css" file reverting back to old state periodically

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

We have a client whose website we did on Wordpress. Admittedly, we are a little new to Wordpress. When adding CSS to the site, we put it in a CSS file located at 'uploads/wp-less-cache/theme-less.css'.

Now, we know this was wrong and we now have a child theme with a style.css to handle all custom CSS added to the site.

The problem now is that theme-less.css is periodically (around daily) reverting back to CSS that we do not want. It is old CSS and it messes up the site. It is overriding the style.css on our child theme.

If anyone has any information on this folder or file, where it comes from or how it changes, it would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !important rule to force your CSS rules, in the child theme style.css, that you feel are most crucial always be applied.